# Mongo model not recognized when import module in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make an app with routes in other folder. In some of the routes, I try to list the itens that I have on my database. But when I use the model name, I gotta error saying that this model is not defined. I defined the model and mongo connection in other folder, then I have included this into the initializer file (app.js). But when I access the route that I wanna, I got the error. I tried to import the db module to the route, but I gotta another error.

here is the route that i wanna access code(routes/blog.js):

```
module.exports = function(app){
    // here i tried import the db module, and doenst worked.

    app.get('/blog', function(req, res){
        Blog.find({}, function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                res.send(result);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

And then it returns that the Blog is not defined, even importing the Model of db. And if the entire db model, say that I'm trying to open a unclose connection.

my code:(database/dbConnection.js):

```
module.exports = function(app){

    //***   mongoose requirement ***
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    //***   Database connection setup ***
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blog_app');

    //*** Schema creatin ***
    var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: String,
        image: String,
        body: String,
        created: {type: Date, dafault: Date.now()}

    });

    //***   Model creation ***
    var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);

};
```

and then, the file that I use to initialize the app.

```
var express = require('express');
var moment = require('moment');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var consign = require('consign');
var app = express();

consign().include('database').then('routes').into(app);


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server running on port 3000. At: " + moment().format('LT'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split your model in another file :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...})

module.exports = mongoose.model('blog', blogSchema)
```

the require it :

```
require('../models/blog')
```

from your route / controller file